# (960gs, Mobile view) Font size increases when using bigger grids

Tags: font-size, 960.gs

My site coded using the 960gs framework works fine on the PC, whereas it has a problem when viewed on a mobile device.

The problem is with font-size, I have two grids with divs having similar properties,

```
<div class="grid_4">
<h2>About Us</h2>
<div class="pBody">
<p>Morbi feugiat pharetra faucibus.</p>
</div>
</div>  

<div class="grid_8">
<h2>Blog Updates</h2>
<div class="preBody">
<p>Morbi feugiat pharetra faucibus.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

The css is similar for both the text divs, I'll list them below,

```
.pBody {
text-align: justify;
color: #858585;
font-size: 13px;
}

.preBody {
text-align: justify;
color: #858585;
font-size: 13px;
}
```

The text in the smaller grid i.e. grid_4 appears normally when viewed on the phone whereas the text in the other div i.e. grid_8 appears bigger. I've removed a few styling divs to keep it short.

I'll attach a screen shot to make things clear,

[image]

I'll be grateful to anyone who could help me out with this.
Regards,
Vinith

Comment: Have you figured it out yet?

Comment: @RRK I couldn't figure out why it was caused. But I fixed the spacing issue by having the same space between words by using the css 'word-spacing' property.